# Как из NavigationController передать переменную в подчиненный TabViewController?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Как из `NavigationController` передать переменную в подчиненный `TabViewController`? В метод prepareForSegue я не попадаю почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Сделал глобальную переменную через Singleton.